# Android game - simulate object rotation along its path

Tags: android, animation, vector, opengl-es

I'm reading [this](http://www.apress.com/9781430246770) awesome Beginning Android Games book, and I'm trying now to implement some tests myself.

I'm using OpenGl ES 1.0, and I'm OK now manipulating the view frustum, projections, translation, rotation, scale etc.

What I'm trying to do:

a) render a rocket to the screen, add some velocity and acceleration to it (using Euler's integration - add the acceleration to the velocity, and the velocity to the position) to simulate a path (parabola). - **This is done, implemented without any issue.**

b) Rotate the rocket, so that we can simulate also the inclination of the object along its path. - **That's the problem.**

To be clear, I'm adding the image below.

[image]

I can't figure out what's the correct angle to add to the rocket, between one frame and the next one.

I tried to get that with some geometry.

[image]

> **Obj Pos 1** is the rocket representation at frame 1.
>
> **Obj Pos 2** is the rocket representation, at the next frame (frame 2).
>
> **V1** is the vector that holds the center X and Y coordinates of the Obj Pos 1.
>
> **V2** i the vector that holds the center X and Y coordinates of the Obj Pos 2.
>
> **Tangent line 1** is the tangent line to the parabola, to where V1 points.
>
> **Tangent line 2** is the tangent line to the parabola, to where V2 points.
>
> **A1** is the angle between both vectors.
>
> **A2** is the angle between both tangent lines.

As far as I can see the correct angle to apply to the rocket, from frame 1 to frame 2 is angle A2. But how can I calculate it?

And, is this correct for game purposes? I mean, we don't need to be exact on the physics concept, we just need to be good enough to simulate animation and 'cheat' the user.

Followd the code below:

```
public class PersonalTest008Rocket extends GLGame {
@Override
public Screen getStartScreen() {
    return new RocketScreen(this);
}

class RocketScreen extends Screen {

    GLGraphics glGraphics;

    Camera2D camera;

    final float WORLD_WIDTH = 60;
    final float WORLD_HEIGHT = 36;

    float[] rocketRawData;
    short[] rocketRawIndices;
    BindableVertices rocketVertices;

    DynamicGameObject rocket;
    float angle;

    Vector2 gravity;

    public RocketScreen(Game game) {
        super(game);

        glGraphics = ((GLGame) game).getGLGraphics();

        camera = new Camera2D(glGraphics, WORLD_WIDTH, WORLD_HEIGHT);

        rocketRawData = new float[]{
                // x, y, r, g, b, a
                +4.0f, +0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1, // 0
                +2.0f, +1.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1, // 1
                +2.0f, -1.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1, // 2
                -2.0f, +1.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1, // 3
                -2.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1, // 4
                -3.0f, +1.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1, // 5
                -3.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1, // 6
                -4.0f, +3.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1, // 7
                -5.0f, +0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1, // 8
                -4.0f, -3.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1 // 9
        };

        rocketRawIndices = new short[]{
                0, 1, 2,
                1, 4, 2,
                1, 3, 4,
                3, 4, 6,
                3, 5, 6,
                3, 7, 5,
                5, 8, 6,
                6, 9, 4
        };

        rocketVertices = new BindableVertices(glGraphics, 10, 3 * 8, true, false);
        rocketVertices.setVertices(rocketRawData, 0, rocketRawData.length);
        rocketVertices.setIndices(rocketRawIndices, 0, rocketRawIndices.length);

        int velocity = 30;
        angle = 45;

        rocket = new DynamicGameObject(0, 0, 9, 6);
        rocket.position.add(1, 1);
        rocket.velocity.x = (float) Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle)) * velocity;
        rocket.velocity.y = (float) Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle)) * velocity;

        gravity = new Vector2(0, -10);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(float deltaTime) {
        rocket.velocity.add(gravity.x * deltaTime, gravity.y * deltaTime);
        rocket.position.add(rocket.velocity.x * deltaTime, rocket.velocity.y * deltaTime);
    }

    @Override
    public void present(float deltaTime) {
        GL10 gl = glGraphics.getGL();

        gl.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1);
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        camera.setViewportAndMatrices();

        gl.glTranslatef(rocket.position.x, rocket.position.y, 0);
        gl.glRotatef(angle, 0, 0, 1);

        rocketVertices.bind();
        rocketVertices.draw(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, rocketRawIndices.length);
        rocketVertices.unbind();
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: You might get some good answers by asking this on the StackExchange Mathematics forum.  Once they can explain the trig/geometry, you can probably figure out the code from that.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the angle based on the instantaneous velocity vector:

```
// Get direction to point the ship
mangleInDeg = (float) (Math.atan2(mRelSpeed.y, mRelSpeed.x)  * 180 / Math.PI);
mangleInDeg += 90.0; // offset the angle to coincide with angle of the base ship image
```